# Error in terminal while activating SSL in VPS Server

Tags: ubuntu, ssl-certificate, hosting, vps, windows-terminal

I'm trying to activate SSL on my VPS server and following all steps as given in this [link](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-lets-encrypt-ssl-on-ubuntu-18-04-with-nginx/)

However in the last step certbot --nginx -d domain.com -d [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com), I'm facing error as shown below:

IMPORTANT NOTES:

- The following errors were reported by the server:

  Domain: flightstrolly.com
  Type:   unauthorized
  Detail: 2a02:4780:a:807:0:2f83:a0dc:a: Invalid response from
  http://flightstrolly.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/awqnlkJw496guB7kvLY4uFu5JtOUyeTqXu2F4pKS5xo:
  404

  Domain: [www.flightstrolly.com](http://www.flightstrolly.com)
  Type:   unauthorized
  Detail: 2a02:4780:a:807:0:2f83:a0dc:a: Invalid response from
  http://www.flightstrolly.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/AQn30l2Qqq2D4kwDAY8Piikm-W0OmsZY1Sp2uir0Jtw:
  404

  To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
  entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
  contain(s) the right IP address.

My domain is flightstrolly.com, and I'm completely blank thow to solve this, anyone can help?